# Catch the end of Return Activity Transition

Tags: android, android-transitions, activity-transition

From Activity **A** to **B** , I set enter and return transitions.
I want to put a fadein animation after the  return transition ( **B** to **A** after a back).

Originally , I thought that in Activity's onStart method will a good place.
It turns out I don't see the fadein animation so I suppose the ending of the Return Transition happens after **onStart()**

I checked with [SharedElementCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SharedElementCallback.html) but it doesn't tell when the transition ends.

How to catch the moment when the Return Transition ends ?

Answer (score 0):

For `Activity` you'll need to call [overridePendingTransition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)) in `Activity` **A** after calling `startActivity()` and provide your own animations.  You can also override `onEnterAnimationComplete()` in `Activity` **A** so you know when it has been animated on to the screen.

For `Fragment`s, you can do this by adding your own custom animations for the transitions using [setCustomAnimations()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) on the transaction.  These will override the default animations for your `Fragment` transitions.